# How to access "this" variable in VSCode debugging?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-code

When debugging JavaScript functions in VSCode, how do you access the `this` value when inside the context of a function? The VSCode Debug Panel only appears to display locally defined values and the arguments to the function. I see everything except the `this` object/property/variable.

The only workaround I've found is to temporarily define a local value: `let whatever = this` so that I can examine `this`. Probably a poor solution but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: [This screenshot](https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/editor/debugging/debug-session.png) seems to indicate you should be able to see `this` in the _Locals_ section

Comment: You can also add `this` to your "watch" section and it works.